# Android - Issue on removing node from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The following function is called from an addChildEventListener to remove a specific node from my Firebase database when it's needed.
The issue here is that the function launches the "Item removed." toast, indicating the task was successfully executed, but the node keeps existing on the database.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

```js
private void showData(DataSnapshot ds) {
    String keyValue = null;

    if(ds.hasChildren()) {
        keyValue = ds.getKey();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Removing item...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        ds.getRef().child(keyValue).removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Item removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Something bad happened while removing item.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
If it helps, my query is the following:

```
orderItemsByTime = db.getInstance().getReference().child("items").orderByChild("time");
```

Comment: Have you tried to remove `.getRef()` when you `addOnCompleteListener`?

Comment: Did it. Unfortunately, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A likely explanation is that `ds.getRef().child(keyValue)` is not pointing to the location you intend.  When `remove()` is performed on a non-existent location, it's not an error.  `task.isSuccessful()` returns true.

Add some debug logging (or toasting) to show the path for `ds.getRef().child(keyValue)`:

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Removing item at " +
        ds.getRef().child(keyValue), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or

```
Log.d(TAG, "Removing item at " + ds.getRef().child(keyValue));
```

Comment: I've added the toast you suggested just after posting this issue here. It shows the specific path I want to remove. Some other suggestion?

Comment: @LavitzBr: Are you sure the path is correct?  Doesn't the key appear twice?  Is that what you want?  Example:  If the path to the snapshot is `/test/post`, the key is `post`, and the path for the remove is `/test/post/post`.

Comment: If it helps, the query I'm using is orderItemsByTime = db.getInstance().getReference().child("items").orderByChild("time"). The toast shows the path all the way to the items' database key that I want to remove; the same path I see when I walk through the database on Firebase console.